# Is there a way to execute BeforeCreate and BeforeUpdate hooks for every struct inside a struct?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following code:

```
type InnerStructA struct {
 A string
}

type InnerStructB struct {
 B string
}

func (a *A) BeforeCreate(scope *gorm.Scope) error {
    return scope.SetColumn("A", uuid.New().String())
}

func (b *B) BeforeCreate(scope *gorm.Scope) error {
    return scope.SetColumn("B", uuid.New().String())
}

type OuterStruct struct {
    InnerStructA
    InnerStructB
    ID      string `gorm:"type:varchar(40);not null"`
}
```

When I create records:

```
outerStructObject := OuterStruct{
        ID:          "sample_ID",
    }
err := db.Create(&outerStructObject).Error
```

only one of the BeforeCreate() hooks gets called. Other BeforeCreate gets skipped.

Gorm version is jinzhu/gorm v1.9.16

Is there a way which makes a call to both hooks when a create statement is called?

Expecting BeforeCreate hooks to be called for both inner structs - InnerStructA and InnerStructB.

Comment: Embedding cannot promote two methods of the same name, obviously. Add an explicit method called BeforeCreate to OuterStruct that calls InnerStructA.BeforeCreate and InnerStructB.BeforeCreate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter's comment is accurate, I'll share my tests and comments here but using the official repo at [go-gorm/gorm](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm) and latest version `v1.25.0` which has very similar results and some changes in the API.

When creating the Outer registry, inner objects can be set like this:

```golang
func (o *OuterStruct) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    fmt.Println("Hook triggered: BeforeCreate for OuterStruct")
    o.InnerStructA.A = uuid.New().String()
    o.InnerStructB.B = uuid.New().String()
    return nil
}
```

To trigger inner objects hooks, only by creating them directly:

```golang
innerA := InnerStructA{
    A: "123",
}

errCreateInner := db.Create(&innerA).Error
```

Here is a complete isolated example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func main() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open(":memory:"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&InnerStructA{}, &InnerStructB{}, &OuterStruct{})

    outerStructObject := OuterStruct{
        ID: "sample_ID",
    }

    errCreate := db.Create(&outerStructObject).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(errCreate)
    }

    var outer OuterStruct
    db.Last(&outer)
    fmt.Println("Last register: ", outer)

    // innerA := InnerStructA{
    //  A: "123",
    // }

    // errCreateInner := db.Create(&innerA).Error
    // if err != nil {
    //  log.Fatal(errCreateInner)
    // }
}

type InnerStructA struct {
    A string
}

type InnerStructB struct {
    B string
}

// This is not being called
func (a *InnerStructA) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    fmt.Println("Hook triggered: BeforeCreate for InnerStructA")
    // ...
    return nil
}

// This is not being called
func (b *InnerStructB) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    fmt.Println("Hook triggered: BeforeCreate for InnerStructB")
    // ...
    return nil
}

// This works!
func (o *OuterStruct) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    fmt.Println("Hook triggered: BeforeCreate for OuterStruct")
    o.InnerStructA.A = uuid.New().String()
    o.InnerStructB.B = uuid.New().String()
    return nil
}

type OuterStruct struct {
    InnerStructA
    InnerStructB
    ID string `gorm:"type:varchar(40);not null"`
}
```